# Are there tools to do a git pull request review in Visual Studio using Azure Devops?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm used to using TFS for code reviews and doing them in the side by side view of Visual Studio.  Now we've switched to Azure DevOps using Git, and when I do my code reviews (pull request) it puts me in the browser.  Are there tools that I can use to bring this functionality back into Visual Studio?  Is there an option that I don't see for this?  It is much easier to review code when I can quickly navigate to other files, definitions, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard way to do that. But you may try this extension from Microsoft DevLabs for VS 2019: [Pull Requests for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEVersionControlMSFT.pr4vs)