# Is it possible to do git pull request review in Visual Studio 2022 using Azure Devops?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I normally review pull requests in the code editor when I code in Visual studio code. I use [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) to review the pull request directly in the editor in Visual Studio Code. I found a thread about this that was several years old with a plugin: [Pull Requests for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280995/15113491).

I wonder if there is any new solution to this problem like **GitHub Pull Requests and Issues**? Or if the old plugin for **Visual studio 2019** is still the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any new solution to this problem like GitHub Pull
> Requests and Issues? Or if the old plugin for Visual studio 2019 is
> still the only solution.

Yes, it is still the only solution to review the pull requests in VS now.

If you don't need to check those pull requests inside the VS tool. There is a extension for VS2022:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.GitHubExtensionforVisualStudio&ssr=false#overview

This extension should be installed by default.

You can create and review pull requests via this button:

[image]

But it will not 'inside' the VS.

If you need the extension 'Pull Requests for Visual Studio' for VS2022, please upvote the suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/manage-pull-request-in-visual-studio-2022-devops-g/1690514) and share your ideas.

Comment: Suggestion already exist. Go vote here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/manage-pull-request-in-visual-studio-2022-devops-g/1690514

Comment: Clicking New Pull Request in VS seems to do nothing but take me to a GitHub page that doesn't know anything about changes I've made in VS.